# Blender is Not Opening

Tags: installation

So I installed Blender today (Windows 10, latest version) & it worked great! Even starting making my very first model ever.

But then I closed it & when I went to reopen the program, all that popped up was a grey console window. Nothing else. I couldn't click anything, admin mode didn't work, & I even uninstalled & reinstalled.

Any idea how to fix this? I did nothing abnormal between closing it & opening it (played an hour of WoW, that's all). Only other download today was Unity & that's working fine as well.

Comment: I do not think this is a blender issue (it was working today) something, video drivers maybe, changed.

Comment: I haven't changed anything except install a couple steam games (but none were installed around the time this issue started). Could updating my drivers work? I reset my laptop recently & have yet to do that